# $CFG->dataroot in Moodle clustering

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to launch several instances of Moodle in a Kubernetes-like container platform to improve performance and make my installation reliable. I came across the [following requirement](https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Server_cluster)

> $CFG->dataroot This MUST be a shared directory where each cluster node
>   is accessing the files directly. It must be very reliable,
>   administrators cannot manipulate files directly.

Which tool can be used to transparently sync this directory across several containers? What is the best way to meet this requirement?

Comment: I think you should add the `Kubernetes` or `container` to your question so experienced people in that field can help you. I think it's possible because I tried it with `pagodabox` using their `Network storage`. They are using containers technologies to manage their instances. The mount the storage using `nfs` to the application instance so the application can access the files.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully resolved the issue by using [ObjectFS plugin](https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-tool_objectfs) for S3 storage and moving sessions to database instead of file system.